# VS 2022 Setup Project Uninstall Registry Key - InstallSource = Package Cache

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

My IT dept. is telling me that usually apps copy the install MSI to ProgramData\PackageCache and updates the registry key to point to this location. They want me to do this. The registry shows this for other apps:

[image]

My apps are not doing it like that as you can see.

[image]

How do I get my apps to copy the MSI to the Package Cache folder and change the InstallLocation registry key? Is there a setting for this in the Setup Project or do I have to do these two steps with a custom action to copy the file and a registry action to edit the key?

This is the first time for me making installers so I'm a little new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing comes from installing an installation package (like an MSI) via a [WiX Bundle](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). If you aren't using a Bundle, you shouldn't find your package in the "Package Cache".